# Bengali font is broken on Idle and Tkinter app

Tags: python, ubuntu, tkinter, fonts

I want to display Bengali text in Tkinter Label or Message widget but its showing box like things instead of text.
I have already tried with installing different font in system and applying them on code but nothing is working. What should I do to display text in Bengali font. 
System detail- Ubuntu 16.04, Python 3.5

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

root = Tk()
msg=Message(root,text='আনন্দবাজার')
msg.config(font=('Lohit Bengali', 54))
msg.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

[App Screenshot with output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/inB7L.png)

Comment: Do you know for certain that you have a font family named "Lohit Bengali" installed on your machine?

Comment: Yes, I have already installed "Lohit Bengali".

Answer (score 0):

You first need to determine whether tcl/tk knows about and can access 'Lohit Bengali'.  Run IDLE and click Options => Configure IDLE and look at the font list. 
Or run

```
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()
from tkinter import font
fams = font.families()
print('Lohit Bengali' in fams)  # answer question above
print()
for fam in sorted(fams):  # To see what tcl does know about
    print(fam)
```

EDIT: add parens to families call

Comment: I do not have a Bengali font installed, but when I pasted 'পাইথন' into IDLE's Shell, with Lucida Console in use, on Windows, it displays properly, the same as here in FireFox.  Windows, or tcl/tk on Windows, is apparently much better about filling in characters than Ubuntu.  Perhaps one of the system fonts you have will do so.  You can experiment with multiple fonts easily with IDLE.  Or you could adapt the program in the answer to print 'পাইথন' with each of the fonts recognized.

Comment: print('Lohit Bengali' in fams)  # answer question above
TypeError: argument of type 'function' is not iterable. This error is showing while I am running the program. By configuring Idle and by changing font face to 'Lohit Bengali' It's showing Bengali but not properly it's still broken and not that much readaable but better than before.

Comment: The posted code was missing `()` after `families`.  Now fixed. You can try it again.

Comment: 'Lohit Bengali' font is in the list and the result is showing 'True'. But Bengali is still broken even I tried 'NotoSansBengali' but still not working.